# configure xserver warning - unrecognized options: --with-fontdir, --with-dri-driver-path

Tags: xorg, xserver

I'm trying to build tigervnc under ubuntu 11.10 32bit.
http://tigervnc.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tigervnc/trunk/BUILDING.txt?revision=4879&view=markup

In the configure step I'm getting a warning:

> configure:
>   WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-fontdir, --with-dri-driver-path

In the make step I'm getting an error:

> In file included from glxdriswrast.c:39:0:
>   /usr/include/GL/internal/dri_interface.h:51:17: fatal error: drm.h: No such file or directory

How can I fix the warning and error?

This is what I'm trying to do following BUILDING.txt:

```
sudo apt-get install cmake

download tigervnc source to /home/tigervnc-1.2.0
download xserver-xorg-dev source to /home/xorg-server-1.10.4
apt-get source xserver-xorg-dev
mkdir build
cd build

mkdir unix
cp -R ../tigervnc-1.2.0/unix/xserver unix/

cp -R ../xorg-server-1.10.4/* unix/xserver/

cd unix/xserver
patch -p1 < ../../../tigervnc-1.2.0/unix/xserver110.patch
sudo apt-get install xutils-dev libtool
autoreconf -fiv

sudo apt-get install libssl-dev libgl1-mesa-dev x11proto-gl-dev x11proto-record-dev x11proto-resource-dev x11proto-scrnsaver-dev x11proto-bigreqs-dev x11proto-xcmisc-dev libxfont-dev x11proto-video-dev libxkbfile-dev

./configure --with-pic --without-dtrace --disable-static --disable-dri \
      --disable-xinerama --disable-xvfb --disable-xnest --disable-xorg \
      --disable-dmx --disable-xwin --disable-xephyr --disable-kdrive \
      --disable-config-dbus --disable-config-hal --disable-config-udev \
      --disable-dri2 --enable-install-libxf86config --enable-glx \
      --with-default-font-path="catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d,built-ins" \
      --with-fontdir=/usr/share/X11/fonts \
      --with-xkb-path=/usr/share/X11/xkb \
      --with-xkb-output=/var/lib/xkb \
      --with-xkb-bin-directory=/usr/bin \
      --with-serverconfig-path=/usr/lib/xorg \
      --with-dri-driver-path=/usr/lib/dri

> configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-fontdir, --with-dri-driver-path

make TIGERVNC_SRCDIR=../../../tigervnc-1.2.0
> In file included from glxdriswrast.c:39:0:
> /usr/include/GL/internal/dri_interface.h:51:17: fatal error: drm.h: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the development version of libdrm: `sudo apt-get install libdrm-dev`.

Note that some distros (Mandriva, Fedora, maybe others) already have tigervnc packaged. You can look at their package specs to see how this is done. Tigervnc is not a simple software to build, you might face many other problems... And I'm not sure stackoverflow.com is the right place to ask these questions.

Mandriva spec file:
http://svn.mandriva.com/viewvc/packages/cooker/tigervnc/current/SPECS/tigervnc.spec?view=markup